# Need to define a dynamic schema for an object in typescript

Tags: typescript

```json
{
            "_id": {
                "date": 1547616778000,
                "time": 1547616778000,
                "timestamp": 1547616778,
                "new": false,
                "timeSecond": 1547616778,
                "inc": 1145588242,
                "machine": -448403429
            },
            "Holiday_Name": "Summer-Returnees",
            "Market": "MAADXB",
            "Analyst": null,
            "Start_date_2018": "2018-08-13",
            "End_date_2018": "2018-09-12",
            "Start_date_2019": "2019-08-10",
            "End_date_2019": "2019-09-16",
            "Start_date_2020": "2020-08-08",
            "End_date_2020": "2020-09-14",
            "Active": "TRUE"
}
```

This is the current event object I am getting from the server as you can see at the bottom the events `Start_date(year)` and `End_date(year)` keys are getting same with a year change. Here I need to create a schema for this object which should be dyanimic.

I tried to define a dynamic schema with typescript new [feature](https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_5_updates.php). But I failed to implement it, I am getting an error that saying.

> Error: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

```js
export type EventsSchema = {    
[ServerKeys.HOLIDAY_NAME]: "Summer-Returnees";    
[ServerKeys.MARKET_]: string;    
[ServerKeys.ANALYST_]: null | string;    
[`Start_date\_${number}`]: string;    
[`End_date\_${number}`]: string;    
[ServerKeys.ACTIVE_]: "TRUE" | "FALSE";  
};
```

Comment: There are a couple of questions I need to ask. First, how will you determine the number of years in the object? And secondly, how will you loop over it?